# MVC - Pass differents models to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Well I want in 1 view create a simple menu and when user click in one link of the menu there should appear a list of items from database.

Character | Races | Classes...

It's kinda silly the way, the links will be a submit in a little form and I will use in controller a Switch (nameSubmit) > Case "valueSubmit" to load some code or other, and return a list of my database I mean

If user click Character, the code will create something like

```
List<personajes> TodosPersonajes = new List<personajes>();
                TodosPersonajes = (from personajes in db.personajes
                                   select personajes).ToList();
                return View(TodosPersonajes);
```

And then in my view I want to write a simple foreach and load the data, my problem is the next

I will use at least 4 differentes types of models from my db (character, classes, races, quests) so I cant write a simple @model XXXXX.Character cause then when user click classes the data isnt valid

I try to do something with Tuple but in a foreach Model.ItemX doesnt work or I dont know how to do it, and in controller I don't know how to create a tuple

im getting error in the first line

```
Tuple<personajes, clases, razas> TuplaPersonajes = new Tuple<personajes, clases, razas>();
```

Comment: Seems like you are fighting against mvc, ideally you would have one view for each model type.  Do your switching in the controller and not in the view.